# Incompatible types on import

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I updated our project to use gradle plugin version 4.1.1 from version 4.0.0. After the update I get a strange compiler error `error: incompatible types: <null> cannot be converted to int` on an `import` line. If I remove that `import` and all the references from the code, I get the same error on the same line (that now has a different `import` in it), so this leads me to believe that the problem is not with the imported class. Before the update, the project had no errors. Reading the changelog of gradle plugin updates I could find no related records. The IDE shows no problems. How could I investigate what the problem actually is?

Comment: Are those imports related to DAO? Because if they are, then there might be some entity based on your database which is expected to be int, but on db level it's nullable and has null values.

Comment: No, the original class holds some info about the server, but the second one is just a strings util class and that still triggers the error.

Comment: Tamás, do you have write access to the second one? Can you detect why is it crashing? Can you do an import for an empty class? Presumably if you import an empty class, no such error will happen. If that's the case, then something happens inside the files that you import. Possibly a missing server variable or something of the like.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the problem was actually in the generated BuildConfig which was imported further up in the file. Gradle 4.1.0 removed the version name and code fields from the BuildConfig so I created custom fields that contained this info but messed up the injection so the version code int variable was injected with null value and that is what was giving me the build error. I don't know why the compiler indicated the error in the wrong place.